# Grails 3.x + Java Gson Marshaler stackoverflow exception

Tags: java, grails, gson

So here it is my problem. I have java class JsonMarshaller.It uses google Gson to convert to json.

```
public String toJson(BaseDoc pojo) {
    return gson.toJson(pojo);
}
```

I do call it from grails controller.

```
String jsonString = new JsonMarshaller().toJson(eadDoc).
```

eadDoc extends BaseDoc and everything works fine. How ever from grails 3.x validateable is no longer annotation, it is interface. If my eadDoc implements it than there is error.

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.util.WeakHashMap.hash(WeakHashMap.java:298)
    at java.util.WeakHashMap.get(WeakHashMap.java:396)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.writeField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:136)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:241)
```

So the question is does anybody else have the same problem. Do you have a solution because I do need this groovy class to be validateable.

Comment: By the way I did forget to mention that I have set the ExclusionStrategy for errors which is one of the solutions I did find but it does not work

Comment: You'll have to exclude whatever property it is looping circularly through. I would recommend GSON views as it handles stuff like this automatically (http://views.grails.org)

Comment: I have the same issue, but with a much simpler case. In bootstrap i have defined a simple marshaller for a domain object. Then in my api controller try to render it, and always get this error.  I have found no solution and am currently hand outputting each field of each domain object in each api - incredibly painful.